# Resizing JFrame from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm curious is there a way to resize window from `JPanel` object. I'm looking for solution for a while. Maybe I'm missing something?

I want to resize window when use `changeSize()` method (f.e. on button, I deleted lot code).

I've tried different methods like `setSize`, `setPreferredSize` and `setBorders`.

```
public class MAIN{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Okno(new Panel_Saper());
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Okno extends JFrame{
    protected Okno(Panel panel) {
        setResizable(true);
        getContentPane();
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(panel);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(panel.getClose());//2 - JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE, 3 - JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class Panel extends JPanel {
    protected int getClose() {return 2;} //2 - JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
}//needed for override in other place
```

---

```
public class Panel_Saper extends Panel {
    Panel_Saper() {
        setLayout(null);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));   
    }

    public void changeSize() {//DOESN'T WORK
        SetSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: A panel resizing a frame is like the tail wagging the dog. General tips: 1) `protected int getClose() {return 2;} //2 - JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` should instead be `protected int getClose() {return JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;` to avoid guessing and make the app. robust to the JVM/JRE changing  the value of the constant! 2) `setLayout(null);` **Don't** do that! Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or ..

Comment: .. [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) `Panel extends JPanel` since the AWT already has a `Panel` class, this is, at best, confusing to other people who read the code. Give the `Panel` a more specific name, like `ClosePanel`. 4)  `SetSize(new Dimension(600,600));` I doubt that would even compile. The method name should start with a lower case letter. 5) `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));` ..

Comment: .. See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: Thx man. So it is not possible to try? I made work around by closing and reopening window ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Program is a lot bigger and has over 1k of buttons so I don't want to use layout.

Comment: *and has over 1k of buttons so I don't want to use layout* - that is exactly why you should be using a layout manager. Unless you application allows users to drag the components randomly on a panel you should be using a layout manager.

Comment: *"Program is a lot bigger and has over 1k of buttons so I don't want to use layout."* So what .. seriously? You are going to programmatically(?) position **over 1,000** buttons? How are they positioned? Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, this is just big minesweeper game within launcher of more games. Few loops to position buttons. I understand importance of layouts, still swing is not too good for such amount of buttons. Cheers. Edit: I  think I'll just make interactive bitmap, so there won't be JButtons at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your custom panel it is preferred that you override the `getPreferredSize()` method. Every Swing component is responsible for knowing its preferred size.

If you want to change the preferred size from 400 to 600 you must have a reason for doing this. So you should have a property for your panel that you can modify.

Then your implementation of the `getPreferredSize()` method will check this property and return the appropriate size depending on the current state of your panel.

> I made work around by closing and reopening window

Now that your component has implemented the `getPreferredSize()` correctly you can simple invoke `pack()` on the JFrame.